# How to efficiently implement a version of Path.exists() with a timeout on Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, python-multithreading, pathlib

The background of my problem is that I use ´Path.exists()´ on windows to check if a network path is available. If it is not, ´Path.exists()´ can block for quite some time (20 seconds or more) before it returns `False`.
This is too long so I want to define a time limit, after which I consider the ressource to be unavailable.
What I came up with is a wrapper class around ´Path´, which uses a `ThreadPoolExecutor` to call `Path`s `exists` method and cancels the call after a timeout:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from pathlib import Path

class TimeoutPath:
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

    def __init__(self, *args, timeout: float = 1, **kwargs):
        self._path = Path(*args, **kwargs)
        self.timeout = timeout

    def exists(self) -> bool:
        future = TimeoutPath.executor.submit(self._path.exists)
        start_time = time.time()
        while (time.time() - start_time) < self.timeout:
            if future.done():
                return future.result()
        future.cancel()
        return False

    def get_path(self) -> Path:
        return self._path

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        return getattr(self._path, name)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._path)
```

This works, but even on a local folder this sometimes returns `False` for an existing folder on a local drive even if the timeout is set to one second, which I assume is due to the overhead that is needed to start the thread.

So I guess my question is: is it possible to reduce the overhead introduced by the thread pool by using another threading/multiprocessing implementation? Or is there another possible solution without threading I'm not seeing?

Comment: It's virtually impossible to teach Python developers event based programming. Polling is not ever a solution.

Comment: please do elaborate

Comment: Ha! This was surprisingly helpful. Thanks! I'll post an update that is way more performant.

Comment: Your proposed answer exchanges one polling approach with another polling approach. There's nothing event-based.

Comment: Well, the wait function is based on the `Event` and `Condition` synchronization primitives in the threading module. Would you care to specify what you mean by event-based?

Comment: Polling on a dedicated thread is still polling. You want to subscribe to a system event instead.

Comment: That just sounds like polling with extra steps :-P
Seriously, though, which system event would that be in my case? The OS being slow to decide if the path exists or not is my problem in the first place. And if there is a suitable event: Subscribing to such an event would require an event loop, right? And how is that so different from polling in a thread?

Comment: Polling is different in that it - like every approach based on sampling - is subject to miss events in between sampling points. Though if registering for events sounds like polling with extra steps to you, then maybe it's not entirely wrong to state: It's virtually impossible to teach Python developers event-based programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [@IInspectable](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1889329/iinspectable) I think I figured out what my mistake was.

Polling the `future.done` method in the while loop creates way too many unnecessary cycles.
`Future.result()` actually already has a timeout parameter and blocks until the future has a result or times out:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, TimeoutError
from pathlib import Path
from typing import Any

class TimeoutPath:
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=1)

    def __init__(self, *args, timeout: float = 1, **kwargs):
        self._path = Path(*args, **kwargs)
        self.timeout = timeout

    def exists(self) -> bool:
        future = TimeoutPath.executor.submit(self._path.exists)
        try:
            return future.result(self.timeout)
        except TimeoutError:
            return False

    def get_path(self) -> Path:
        return self._path

    def __getattr__(self, name: str) -> Any:
        return getattr(self._path, name)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return str(self._path)
```

On my machine this works quite reliably for timeouts of 2 ms.

Comment: I got tired of waiting for a network path (that I know isn't there) to fail.  I appreciate this!